# link individual user's profile to user in comment section - Django

Tags: python, django

I need to link respective user's profile to the comments. Currently all my links are taking me to the logged in user's profile itself.

My user model @ user_profile/models.py:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):        
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=254, unique=True)        
    .......
    .......

    objects = manager.CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%s/" % urlquote(self.email)
```

My profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                related_name="profile",
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, default='')
    .....
    .....

    objects = manager.CustomProfileManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("user_profile:commenters_profile")

    @property
    def get_profile(self):
        instance = self
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
        return content_type
```

Comments/models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='comment_by', default=1)
    ....
```

View:

```
@login_required
def commenters_profile(request):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Profile)

    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance.get_profile(),
        }
    return render(request, "profile.html", context)
```

user_profile/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', myProfile, name='myProfile'),
    url(r'^$', commenters_profile, name='commenters_profile'),
]
```

template:

```
<p><a href="{{ comment.user.profile.get_absolute_url }}"> {{ comment.user.get_full_name }}</a></p>
```

Please help.

**Update:**

**Traceback** (most recent call last):

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/surajit/website/PubNet/user_profile/views.py", line 173, in commenters_profile
    "instance": instance.get_profile(),
TypeError: 'ContentType' object is not callable
```

**profile.html:**

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-3">
            <img src="{{ user.profile.photo.url }}", width="220", alt="", class="img-rounded img-responsive" />
            <br/><p> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> {{ user.email }}
                <br /> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></i> {{ user.date_of_birth }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6">
            <blockquote>
                <p><h2>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</h2></p>
                <small><cite title="Source Title">Some Text Here <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i></cite></small>
            </blockquote>
            <br/><p> {{ user.profile.bio }}</p>
        </div>
```

**Screenshot of Comments Section:**

[image]

Comment: is the names displayed of the user who commented?

Comment: yes. The name is being displayed correctly. I think my view is not correct. However, I am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Because `myProfile` and `commenters_profile` have same regular expressions, you never reach `commenters_profile`, all request will be send to `myProfile`. Change `commenters_profile` url:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', commenters_profile, name='commenters_profile'),
```

fix `get_absolute_url` method:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("user_profile:commenters_profile", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

and view:

```
@login_required
def commenters_profile(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=pk)

    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance.get_profile(),
        }
    return render(request, "profile.html", context)
```

Comment: Gives an error " commenters_profile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk' ". what changes do I make in view?

Comment: I did the same thing but its now giving me a TypeError "'ContentType' object is not callable".

Comment: without get_profile did not work. links to the logged in user profile only. I have updated my question with traceback and get_profile()

Comment: instance.get_profile() was a typo. I have added a screenshot of the comment section and it does shows two different users. Have also attached the profile.html.

Comment: changing {{ user.xxxx }} to {{ instance.xxxx }} is unable to retrieve data. No error though. :(

Comment: Removed get_profile and changed to "instance": instance.user . With instance in template, it worked. Thank you @neverwalkaloner for your patience. :)